# Laravel, Validator check if two columns exist in same table

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

i have 3 parameters (br_code,slc_code,slt_code)
im done with validations for br_code and slc_code

to validate slt_code, i have to check if slc_code and slt_code exist on table(sltype) , how do i do it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0m4rT.png)

thankyou

i tried this code but it give me different respond like its storing instead of checking
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM8Sk.png)

Comment: you can pull the value of the fields from the `$request` object itself

Comment: Please don't add an image of your code in question instead add your actual code.